# How can I submit unsubmitted Moodle attempt via SQL

Tags: moodle

Hello I ma trying to submit unsubmitted quiz attempts so I can grade them. So far I have set the timefinish column in mdl_quiz_attempts which changes the attempt status to "Not yet graded", then setting fraction to 0 from NULL and state to "gradewrong" from "complete" in mdl_question_attempt_steps to simulate submission but this seems to break the site. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to trace through the code for the process_finish() function in mod/quiz/attemptlib.php ( https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/mod/quiz/attemptlib.php#L2171 ) and figure out how that all works.

This is a complex process and will require a lot of DB queries / updates in order to achieve it manually.

I would strongly recommend that you write a PHP script to do this, instead of trying to handle it manually (that way you can create an instance of 'quiz_attempt' for each user's attempt, then call $attempt->process_finish() on each, in order to close the attempt properly).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. The trick is to set the `timefinish` column in `mdl_quiz_attempts` which changes the attempt status to "Not yet graded", then setting the state to "gradewrong" from "complete" in `mdl_question_attempt_steps` for unsubmitted responses to simulate submission. Then set a fake 0 grade to `sumgrades` where grades are NULL in `mdl_quiz_attempts` and then running a regrade in the admin panel.